# Access child elements of a custom directive without jQuery

Tags: angularjs

I've written a custom directive for a dropdown menu. The elements are absolutely positioned within a relatively positioned parent, so I need to get the height of the dropdown trigger element in order to move the actual menu below it. The trigger is a child of the directive element. I want to avoid using full-blown jQuery and instead use Angular's jqLite.

My attempt so far consists of a function added to the scope inside the directive's link function (so as to have access to `element`), but I'm not able to chain either `find()` or `children()` off that to find the child element.

My link and controller:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.clicked = false;
    scope.positionDropdown = function() {
        if (!scope.clicked) {
            scope.clicked = true;
            scope.buttonHeight = element[0].find('button').offsetHeight;
        }
    }
},
controller: function($scope) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.menuActive = false;
    $scope.toggleMenu = function () {
        $scope.positionDropdown();
        $scope.menuActive = !$scope.menuActive;
    };
}
```

What this should do is, when the button is first clicked, the scope variable `buttonHeight` should be defined with the element's height. Instead, I get an error in Chrome Dev Tools:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.scope.positionDropdown (http://localhost:3000/directives/dropdown/dropdown-directive.js:17:57)
    at Scope.$scope.toggleMenu (http://localhost:3000/directives/dropdown/dropdown-directive.js:25:28)
    at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:10656:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:18838:17
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:12518:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:12616:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:18837:21)
    at http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:2810:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/angular/angular.js:320:11)
```

Here's my template:

```
<div class="dropdown" ng-class="{active: menuActive}">
<button ng-click="toggleMenu()">{{ngLabel}}<i ng-class="ngIcon" ng-if="ngIcon"></i></button>
<ul ng-show="menuActive" ng-style="{top: buttonHeight}"ng-transclude>
</ul>
```

I've set up a breakpoint to play around with this. `element[0]` works, but the `find()` method off that gives me `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. `element[0].children(document.querySelector('button'))` also errors with the same result. Why don't these methods of selecting the dropdown menu work? How can I select this without resorting to jQuery and without limiting myself to a single dropdown on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't get your question but if you want to select child of an element in Angular, you could do this:

```
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

            // to select parent of parent of current element : 
            elem.parent().parent();
             // to select parent of current element : 
            elem.parent();
             // to select Child(a) of current element : 
            elem.children('a');
            // to select all Childs of current element : 
            elem.children();
            // getting element height
            elem.height();
            // window height : 
             $(window).height();
             // document height:
             $(document).height();
             // distance of your elem to top of the page : 
             $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();




    }
```

Comment: This got me where I needed to be. `element[0]` is needed to select the element, but the jqLite methods won't chain off that for some reason. Dropping `[0]` made it work. Now, my problem is that jqLite has no way to calculate the height of the element. :-/ Thanks!

Comment: .height() is not a function

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an Id on the button in question, eg `<button id="myTrigger"></button>`, and then use:

`angular.element($document.getElementById('#myTrigger'));`

Alternatively, loop through the children using `elem.children()`, and look for a button type.

Comment: I want to avoid this because using an ID might cause problems if I have multiple menus on a page.

Comment: That's fine. Just loop through the children looking for a button.